# Server-side validation of contact form POST using PHP and a secret is returning false when it should be true

Tags: php, html, validation, md5, contact-form-7

So basically I have a contact form that I send using the mail() function and I implemented several validations like reCaptcha and patterns, honeypots, etc. and it works great, but not perfect and client is picky wants even less spam. Right now I'm trying to add a server-side validation using a secret hash as seen here https://css-tricks.com/serious-form-security/

I'd like to insist on the fact that everything works perfectly without the `verifyFormToken('form1')` added condition. I have checked and the function returns true when I remove the first condition and the last condition, so it has to do with the token on the server. I am trying to get rid of the few last spam emails that i assume are sent bypassing entirely my form/JS and POSTing directly. I also checked a few existing questions including this one [PHP form key bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654395/php-form-key-bug)

```php
require_once './php/recaptcha/src/autoload.php';
$siteKey = 'xxxxx';
$secret = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$recipient = "sales@xxxx.com";
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $telephone \n Company: $company \n Message: $message";
$subject = "Contact Form - QUOTE APPLICATION - EN";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
$gRecaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']; //google captcha post data
$remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //to get user's ip
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp); //method to verify captcha

session_start();

function generateFormToken($form) {
  $_SESSION[$form.'_token'] = md5(uniqid(microtime(), true));
  return $_SESSION[$form.'_token'] ;
}

function verifyFormToken($form) {
  if (!isset($_SESSION[$form.'_token'])) { return false;}
  if (!isset($_POST['token'])) {return false;}
  if ($_SESSION[$form.'_token'] !== $_POST['token']) {return false;}
  return true;
}


if(isset($_POST['submit_client'])) {
    $newToken = generateFormToken('form1'); 
    $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
    $gRecaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']; //google captcha post data
    $remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //to get user's ip
    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp); //method to verify captcha
    
            if (($resp->isSuccess()) && (!empty($name)) && (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name))  && (!empty($telephone)) && (preg_match("/^[0-9-+\s()]*$/", $telephone)) && (!empty($email)) && (preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $email))) {
                        
                        if (verifyFormToken('form1')) {
                        mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
                        echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Thank you, we\'ll be in touch shortly!");</script>';
                        }}
            else {
                die("Error!");
            }
}
```

```html
     <form style="position:relative;" class="contact-us-form contact-us-form2" method="POST">
        <h2 class="">quote request</h2>
        <div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;">
        <fieldset>
          <input name="name" placeholder="Name*" type="text" tabindex="1" required pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*$" autofocus>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <input name="email" placeholder="Email*" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" tabindex="2" required>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;">
        <fieldset>
          <input name="telephone" placeholder="Telephone*" type="text" pattern="[0-9-+\s()]*$" tabindex="3" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <input name="company" placeholder="Company" type="text" tabindex="4">
          <input name="token" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $newToken; ?>">
        </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;">
        <fieldset>
          <textarea name="message" placeholder="Tell us more about your request*" rows="8" cols="30" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
         <div id="send-captcha-container">
          <input name="token" type="hidden" value="<?=$newToken;?>">
          <input id="submit-client-button" class="cta contact-form-submit-btn" style="cursor:pointer;border:none!important;" type="submit" name="submit_client" value="send" disabled>
          <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptcha_callback" data-expired-callback="recaptcha_expired_callback" data-sitekey="6Ldcw70ZAAAAAMkOcdoWhQPn8ey2opCbwRIZJe5M"></div>
         </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: you need a send button ;-)

Comment: of course haha i stripped it for the demo. sorry if i wasnt clear. but your #2 might just be my issue. ill confirm and mark as accepted if it works fingers crossed

Comment: If you want to delete the question then you can un-accept the answer and delete the question, but please don't vandalise it

Comment: thanks for that but still cant. which is why i tried more muscular ways but hmm, seems i still cant? // why couldn't I delete my own question, what is this about seriously

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Comment: @RyanM thanks for that, I am fully aware of the license here, however I felt this question went nowhere and it was better if deleted but I understand it can't. So I guess I will try and ask less questions in the future since I can't control them afterwards? Thanks again.

Comment: @avia I just remembered that you can [contact](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) SE and request to anonymise your question, they will detach your account from this question (They did it for me one)

Answer (score 2):

#### There where 2 Mistakes:

1. first mistake is you need a submit button that sends the POST Variable "submit_client"
   because you are checking for it.
2. second mistake is you must make the token after the verify so it is not modified before the sending per POSt

```php
require_once './php/recaptcha/src/autoload.php';
$siteKey = 'xxxxx';
$secret = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$recipient = "sales@oxoinnovation.com";
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $telephone \n Company: $company \n Message: $message";
$subject = "Contact Form - QUOTE APPLICATION - EN";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
$gRecaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']; //google captcha post data
$remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //to get user's ip
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp); //method to verify captcha

session_start();

function generateFormToken($form) {
  $_SESSION[$form.'_token'] = md5(uniqid(microtime(), true));
  return $_SESSION[$form.'_token'] ;
}

function verifyFormToken($form) {
  if (!isset($_SESSION[$form.'_token'])) { return false;}
  if (!isset($_POST['token'])) {return false;}
  if ($_SESSION[$form.'_token'] !== $_POST['token']) {return false;}
  return true;
}


if(isset($_POST['submit_client'])) {

    /*
       Take this out here
    */  
    // $newToken = generateFormToken('form1'); 


    $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
    $gRecaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']; //google captcha post data
    $remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //to get user's ip
    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp); //method to verify captcha
    
            if (($resp->isSuccess()) && (!empty($name)) && (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name))  && (!empty($telephone)) && (preg_match("/^[0-9-+\s()]*$/", $telephone)) && (!empty($email)) && (preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $email))) {
                        
                        if (verifyFormToken('form1')) {
                        mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
                        echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Thank you, we\'ll be in touch shortly!");</script>';
                        }}
            else {
                die("Error!");
            }
}


/*
     and put it here 
*/ 
$newToken = generateFormToken('form1');
```

Comment: hmm it still goes to die('Error') :(

Comment: i can give you access to a clone copy of the website on a separate dev server if you want to look...

Comment: update your question with the real code.  or simply move this line : `$newToken = generateFormToken('form1'); ` after the if clause `if(isset($_POST['submit_client'])) {` With other words generate it after you checked it ..

Comment: Thanks for the help. Hm didn't work so I posted full HTML and PHP

Comment: just so we're clear everything else works 100% tested been live for months

Comment: I modified your code

Comment: awesome let me try it thanks

Comment: I do not log into your server, delete the credentials.

Comment: ok cool. I'll try another solution for server validation as obviously css-tricks solution is flawed in design